# histogram of length of words debug

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) { 
FILE *fp; 
fp = fopen("test.txt", "r"); 

int char_counter, i, c; 
int word_length[12]; 

char_counter = 0; 
for (i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    word_length[i] = 0; 
}

while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ')
    {
        word_length[char_counter] = word_length[char_counter] + 1;
        char_counter = 0; 
    }
    else {
        ++char_counter; 
    }
}

for (i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    printf("%d  %d\n", i, word_length[i]); 
}

return 0; 
}
```

test.txt:

> blahblahblah blahblah blah bla bl b b

Output:

```
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   1
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  -1 <-- ??
```

Expected output looks the same but there should be a 1 at row 12 and not -1. I don't really  understand how I got a negative number.

Comment: are you doing the KandR exercise 1-13 / 1-14 ?

Comment: I have posted exercise 1-13. If you want I'll also post exercise 1-14

Comment: For your given input, the statistics are wrong; you show 2 single letter words (`b`, twice).  And your array `int word_length[12];` has elements `word_length[0]` through `word_length[11]`, so you're accessing out of bounds — hence the bad data.  Make your array big enough!  And write code to handle 'N or more' for the maximum length of string `N` that you're prepared to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
int word_length[12];
```

means that you have 12 items in the list numbered 0 .. 11

The trying to access item 12 you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Look at this snippt:

```
int word_length[12]; 

char_counter = 0; 
for (i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    word_length[i] = 0; 
}
```

Did you find the bug? Hint: Check the number `12` and the operator `<=` again.

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Thanks. I will modify the answer

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Were you attempting to post it as an answer? Hahaha! I won the race

Comment: @Magtheridon96 I believe they were very useful :p

Comment: Great thanks! I appreciate the hint and not giving me the answer right away :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `int word_length[12];` that means it can store max `12` int number which are 0 to 11,
So, `word_length[12]` does not get accessible, so its give some garbage value.

You need to do `int word_length[13];` and your issue ll be resolved.

Comment: Thank you! I understand my error now.

Answer (score 0):

**KnR Exercise 1-3**

```
#include 

#define TAB_STOP 8
#define MAX_WORD_TABS 4
#define MAX_WORD MAX_WORD_TABS * TAB_STOP

int main() {

    int c, i, is_first = 1, skip_space = 1, skip_tab = 0;
    long word_c = 0, word_l = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n') {
            word_l++;
            skip_space = 0;
            if (is_first) {
                ++word_c;
                is_first = 0;
            }
            putchar(c);
        } else {
            is_first = 0;
            if (!skip_space) {

                if (word_l  0; --word_l)
                    printf("|||||");                    //putchar('|');

                putchar('\n');

                skip_space = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use redirection (<, > or >>) on UNIX for input and output of the program... File handling isn't necessary.